# Rename file extension of selected file from dialog box vb.net

Tags: vb.net

I am trying to rename the file extension of a file I selected from the dialog box. Right now, it is not changing format to ".txt". Where am I wrong?

```
 Private Sub Button4_Click(sender As Object, e As EventArgs) Handles Button4.Click
        'Sym File Open
        Dim sym As OpenFileDialog = New OpenFileDialog()

        ''Defines the critieria of a Trace file type.
        sym.Title = "Open File Dialog"
        sym.InitialDirectory = "C:\My Computer\Documents"
        sym.Filter = "Symbol files (*.sym*)|*.sym*"
        sym.FilterIndex = 1
        sym.RestoreDirectory = True

        'Assigning path to textbox
        If sym.ShowDialog() = DialogResult.OK Then
            SymTextSelection.Text = sym.FileName
            'Converting sym file into a text file
            sym.FileName = sym.FileName.Replace(".sym", ".txt")
        End If

    End Sub
```

Comment: System.IO.Path.ChangeExtension()

Comment: I put that instead of `sym.FileName = ""`?

Comment: It returns a string so you would do that instead of the replace call.  Read the documentation and it tells you exactly how to use it with examples

Comment: Thanks, this worked for me `File.Move(sym.FileName, Path.ChangeExtension(sym.FileName, ".xlsm"))`

Answer (score 0):

This worked for me

```
 Private Sub Button4_Click(sender As Object, e As EventArgs) Handles Button4.Click
        'Sym File Open
        Dim sym As OpenFileDialog = New OpenFileDialog()

        ''Defines the critieria of a Trace file type.
        sym.Title = "Open File Dialog"
        sym.InitialDirectory = "C:\My Computer\Documents"
        sym.Filter = "Symbol files (*.sym*)|*.sym*"
        sym.FilterIndex = 1
        sym.RestoreDirectory = True

        'Assigning path to textbox
        If sym.ShowDialog() = DialogResult.OK Then
            SymTextSelection.Text = sym.FileName
            'Converting sym file into a text file
            File.Move(sym.FileName, Path.ChangeExtension(sym.FileName, ".xlsm"))
        End If

    End Sub
```

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).